# Writing a client to connect to websocket in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a websocketed based server/client application using spring boot.

The server accepts a socket connection then when it recieves a text message from the client it will process it, then return some data. The server has a websocket handler that will correctly process a request.

```
public class DataWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataWebSocketHandler.class);

private final DataService dataService;

@Autowired
public DataWebSocketHandler(DataService dataService) {
    this.dataService = dataService;
}

@Override
public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) {
    logger.debug("Opened new session in instance " + this);
}

@Override
public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] payload = this.dataService.getDataBytes(message.getPayload());
    session.sendMessage(new BinaryMessage(payload));
}

@Override
public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception)
        throws Exception {
    session.close(CloseStatus.SERVER_ERROR);
}

}
```

and registered

```
@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(dataWebSocketHandler(), "/data").withSockJS();
}
```

**My problem is, is that I have no idea how to write a client that can connect to the server(assuming I wrote the server correctly) and by extensions how to send the message and how to receive that data on the client side.**

I've failed to find an example of this, but there are plenty where a websocket is written that broadcasts to all clients subscribed to a socket, which I don't want.

The server uses the embeded tomcat server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/main/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-websocket-jetty/src/test/java/smoketest/websocket/jetty/echo

this is a similar server side code..

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-websocket-jetty/src/test/java/smoketest/websocket/jetty/SampleWebSocketsApplicationTests.java

And here is the client side.. using org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient ad some othe configuration.

I believe you can figure out the rest ;)

Cheers

Comment: Link only answers are not the best.

Comment: Apparently, they moved those samples :(

Comment: Links do not work.